# A propriedade 'data' não existe no tipo 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'. ts(2322)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, react, react-dom

Português:

> O tipo '{ data: undefined; }' não pode ser atribuído ao tipo
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
>   Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.   A
>   propriedade 'data' não existe no tipo 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{
>   children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2322)

Inglês:

> Type '{ data: undefined; }' is not assignable to type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
>   Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.   Property
>   'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{
>   children?: ReactNode; }>'.  TS2322

---

**App.tsx:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

import Graph from './components/Graph'


interface Props{}
export default class App extends Component<Props>{
    state = {
        data: undefined
    }

    render(){return(
        <Graph data={this.state.data}/>
    )}
}
```

**Graph.tsx:**

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react'
import {LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} from 'recharts'


interface Props{}
export default class Graph extends PureComponent<Props>{
    render(){return(
        <LineChart width={1000} height={600} data={this.props.data} margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray='3 3'/>
            <XAxis dataKey='timestamp'/>
            <YAxis/>
            <Tooltip/>
            <Legend/>
            <Line type='monotone' dataKey='ping' stroke='#8884d8' activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
        </LineChart>
    )}
}
```

Não estou conseguindo passar o *state* `data` para o *Component* `Graph` via *props*. Alguma solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `state` deve ser inicializado dentro do construtor da classe:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';    
import Graph from './components/Graph';   

interface Props{}
export default class App extends Component<Props>{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: undefined
    };
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Graph data={this.state.data}/>
    );
  }
}
```